# Is there a pandas function to duplicate each row of a dataframe n times, assigning each of n categories to each row?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to go from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2,3], 'col2': [2,4,3,5]})
group_l = ['a', 'b']
df

    col1    col2
0    1       2
1    1       4
2    2       3
3    3       5
```

to

```
    col1    col2    group
0    1       2       a
1    1       4       a
2    2       3       a
3    3       5       a
0    1       2       b
1    1       4       b
2    2       3       b
3    3       5       b
```

I've thought of a few solutions but none seem great.

- Use pd.MultiIndex.from_product, then reset_index. This would work fine if the initial DataFrame only had one column.
- Add a new column `group` where each element is `['a', 'b']`. Use pd.DataFrame.explode. Feels inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

using the `keys` parameter in `pd.concat` is one way:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*len(group_l),keys = group_l,names = ['group']).reset_index(level=0)
```

or

```
df2 = pd.merge(df,pd.Series(group_l,name = 'group'),how = 'cross').sort_values('group')
```

Output:

```
  group  col1  col2
0     a     1     2
1     a     1     4
2     a     2     3
3     a     3     5
0     b     1     2
1     b     1     4
2     b     2     3
3     b     3     5
```

Comment: Hm a bit verbose but probably not going to get too much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

You might create copies, set group value accordingly and concatenate them, that is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,1,2,3], 'col2': [2,4,3,5]})
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df1['group'] = 'A'
df2['group'] = 'B'
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])
print(df_out)
```

gives output

```
   col1  col2 group
0     1     2     A
1     1     4     A
2     2     3     A
3     3     5     A
0     1     2     B
1     1     4     B
2     2     3     B
3     3     5     B
```

Comment: Very bad smell code. If in list we have 600 value, what do you do??

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
group_l = ['a', 'b']
res = pd.concat([df.assign(group=e) for e in group_l])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   col1  col2 group
0     1     2     a
1     1     4     a
2     2     3     a
3     3     5     a
0     1     2     b
1     1     4     b
2     2     3     b
3     3     5     b
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `concat` and `numpy.repeat`?

```
pd.concat([df]*len(group_l)).assign(group=np.repeat(group_l, len(df)))
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 group
0     1     2     a
1     1     4     a
2     2     3     a
3     3     5     a
0     1     2     b
1     1     4     b
2     2     3     b
3     3     5     b
```

Comment: What do you think about speed of explode method vs concat method???

Comment: @Alireza does `explode` yield the values in the correct order? Should give a/b/a/b/…

Comment: Yes return the values with correct order

Answer (score 0):

solving this based on pandas method:

use from explode method

```py
df['group'] = df.col1.map(lambda w: group_l)

df = df.explode('group')
```

Also you can Use from repeat method